# F2PY gives unresolved externals error with PRINT

Tags: gcc, cygwin, gfortran, f2py

I have some FORTRAN code that I want to compile with F2PY. The code is as follows:

```
C FILE: FTYPE.F
      SUBROUTINE FOO(N)
      INTEGER N
Cf2py integer optional,intent(in) :: n = 13
      REAL A,X
      COMMON /DATA/ A,X(3)
      PRINT*, "abc"
      END
C END OF FTYPE.F
```

When I run the following command from Powershell:

```
f2py -c .\ftype.f -m ftype --compiler=msvc
```

I get the following errors:

```
ftype.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write referenced in function foo_
ftype.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_transfer_character_write referenced in function foo_
ftype.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write_done referenced in function foo_
.\ftype.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Based on other answers I have seen here, I feel that I may not be linking to a required library. Here is the entire output:

```
PS C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\F2PY> f2py -c .\ftype.f -m ftype --compiler=msvc

C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\F2PY>call "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\\..\python.exe" "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\\f2py.py" -c .\ftype.f -m ftype --compiler=msvc
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  commands have different --compiler options: ['mingw32', 'msvc'], using first in list as default
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "ftype" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.c
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file '.\\ftype.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
        Block: ftype
                        Block: foo
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "ftype"...
                Constructing wrapper function "foo"...
                  foo([n])
                Constructing COMMON block support for "data"...
                  a,x
        Wrote C/API module "ftype" to file "c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.c"
        Fortran 77 wrappers are saved to "c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.f"
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.210\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin64\bin\DF.exe
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin64\bin\gfortran.exe
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'ftype' extension
compiling C sources
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7
C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC /Tcc:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.c /Foc:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.obj
C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC /Tcc:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c /Foc:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.obj
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\cygwin64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O0
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\cygwin64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O0
Fortran fix compiler: C:\cygwin64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O0
compile options: '-Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c'
gfortran.exe:f77: .\ftype.f
gfortran.exe:f77: c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.f
C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /EXPORT:initftype c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.obj c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.obj c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\ftype.o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.o /OUT:.\ftype.pyd /IMPLIB:c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype.lib /MANIFESTFILE:c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype.pyd.manifest
ftypemodule.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'initftype' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype.lib and object c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype.exp
ftype.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write referenced in function foo_
ftype.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_transfer_character_write referenced in function foo_
ftype.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write_done referenced in function foo_
.\ftype.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
error: Command "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda2\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /EXPORT:initftype c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.obj c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.obj c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\ftype.o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.o /OUT:.\ftype.pyd /IMPLIB:c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype.lib /MANIFESTFILE:c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpra_1ng\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype.pyd.manifest" failed with exit status 1120
```

When I comment the PRINT statement in the FORTRAN code, there is no error, and the code compiles.

I am using GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.4.0. I am using Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit). I think I am using Visual C++ for Python. My operating system is Windows 10.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I do not see Cygwin in any tool you are using. The error is due to missing link with a Fortran shared lib. Do you have a Fortran import library for your compiler ?

Comment: The FORTRAN compiler is installed as part of Cygwin, here: C:\cygwin64\bin\gfortran.exe. But I do not know how to check whether I have a Fortran import library for my compiler. Which folder would I find it in? Sorry, I am not very knowledgeable

Comment: There are two files, libgfortran.dll.a and libgfortran.a, located in the folder C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0. And I think we are linking to the folder, right?

Comment: `error LNK2019` is not coming from the cygwin linker so you are mixing cygwin and not cygwin tools. It will never work. If you want to try with Cygwin you need to use the Cygwin python as start.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like you're using a native Windows Python from Anaconda.  Conda packages gfortran as well, so you should either use all tools provided in a conda environment, or all tools from Cygwin, but don't try to mix the two unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me, based on the comments above.

1. I installed MinGW, using the following instructions and settings for Windows

   [f2py import Fortran code in Python](https://www.scivision.co/f2py-running-fortran-code-in-python-on-windows/)
2. I ran the following command in PowerShell:

   f2py -c ftype.f -m ftype --compiler=mingw32
3. I ran the following command in python:

   import ftype

   ftype.foo(5)
4. I got the following output:

   abc

Below is the entire trace, if you are curious. Overall, I think having all the tools from one place (MinGW) might have helped, as in Iguananaut's comment above (Thank you!).

Thank you all for the help!

```
PS C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\F2PY> f2py -c ftype.f -m ftype --compiler=mingw32

C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\F2PY>call "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\\..\python.exe" "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\\f2py.py" -c ftype.f -m ftype --compiler=mingw32
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "ftype" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.c
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'ftype.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
        Block: ftype
                        Block: foo
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "ftype"...
                Constructing wrapper function "foo"...
                  foo([n])
                Constructing COMMON block support for "data"...
                  a,x
        Wrote C/API module "ftype" to file "c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.c"
        Fortran 77 wrappers are saved to "c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.f"
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
Cannot build msvcr library: "msvcr90d.dll" not found
customize Mingw32CCompiler
customize Mingw32CCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin64\bin\DF.exe
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\mingw\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'ftype' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7
compile options: '-DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1500 -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c'
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1500 -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.c -o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.o
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1500 -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c -o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.o
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\mingw\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O0
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\mingw\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O0
Fortran fix compiler: C:\mingw\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O0
compile options: '-Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c'
gfortran.exe:f77: ftype.f
gfortran.exe:f77: c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.f
C:\mingw\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftypemodule.o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\ftype.o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl\src.win-amd64-2.7\ftype-f2pywrappers.o -LC:\mingw\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0 -LC:\Anaconda2\libs -LC:\Anaconda2\PCbuild\amd64 -LC:\Anaconda2\PC\VS9.0\amd64 -lpython27 -lgfortran -o .\ftype.pyd
Removing build directory c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpt0zwdl
PS C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\F2PY> python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ftype
>>> ftype.foo(5)
 abc
```